# What function/method should I use for file_directory_path()?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 6, I am using the following code.

```
$id = fileowner(file_directory_path());
```

What is the Drupal 8 equivalent of that code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code.

```
$real_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_build_uri(''));
```

On my test site, it returns `'/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/avpnet/sites/default/files'`.

You can also pass a filename to `file_build_uri()`.

```
$real_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_build_uri('file.jpeg'));
```

With this code, I get `'/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/avpnet/sites/default/files/file.jpeg'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem::realpath()` to get the realpath of the file or  `\Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem::dirname()`. As file_directory_path() is deprecated from Drupal 7. For more details please visit at [drupal_realpath](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/8.2.x) and [drupal_dirname](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_dirname/8.2.x)